# Cannot actually use VPN while it's connected?

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, pptp

I've just set up a VPN on my server running Windows Server 2008 R2, but I just found out that even after I've connected to it (PPTP), the traffic does *not* seem to go through the VPN at all. In other words, I'm still actually using my local network to access the Internet when the VPN is connected.

Why is this happening and how can I properly route traffic through the VPN?

Comment: The server is also on your local network?

Comment: Thanks guys! It finally turned out to be a configuration problem on my server side, I didn't correctly setup NAT and now everything works all right!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually another setting you have to configure on the client (not the VPN server). What is your client's platform? You didn't mention that...

For Apple devices, you have to go to your VPN properties and check/tick "Send all traffic over VPN connection."

For Windows devices, you have to go to your VPN properties, "Network" tab, select "Internet Protocol (TCP/IP)," click "Advanced," and check/tick "Use default gateway on remote network."

Once configured, all traffic should route through your VPN utilizing your existing Internet connection.